# How to limit number of entries from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

Im trying to get some values from mysql and echo each value  inside an article. Everything is working fine , I just wanna know how to limit page articles to 15 per page  and when the limit is reached create page #2 etc , Here is the php code im using

```
$query = "SELECT `text` FROM `items` ORDER BY 'id'"; 
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query))     

    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $text = $query_row['text'];     
        echo "<article>$text</article>";
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error($conn_error);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with HTML. Add a `LIMIT` clause to your SQL query.

```
select `text` from `items` order by 'id' limit 15
```

Read up on [SQL Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+pagination).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @meagar's answer: `mysql` is deprecated. You should use the  `mysqli` improved API.

Example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'databasename');
$query = "SELECT `text` FROM `items` ORDER BY 'id' LIMIT 15";


if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $text = $row['text'];     
        echo "<article>$text</article>";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will use mysqli , About the limit i knew how to do it , My question is how to make page #2 when i have like 20 articles queried from the database ,i wanna see 15 articles in page #1 and 5 articles in page #2 etc, Thanks again .